# Vitest mocking and conversion to <unknown>

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, vitest

in my code I have a factory method that produces an object based on injected dependencies:

```
const myFactory = (myRepository : Repository) => ({
    myMethod()  {
        return myRepository.repositoryMethod();
    }
})
```

then in my vitest test I want to mock `myRepository` when testing `myFactory` output:

```
const myRepositoryMock = <Repository><unknown>{
    repositoryMethod: vi.fn(),
}

describe('MyFactory test suite', () => {
    it('myMethod test', () => {

        const repositoryMethod = vi.spyOn(myRepositoryMock, 'repositoryMethod')
            .mockReturnValue({ foo: 'bar' })

        const myService = myFactory(myRepositoryMock);

        expect(myService.myMethod()).toStrictEqual({ foo: 'bar' });
        expect(repositoryMethod).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
    });
});
```

so far, so good - it all works as expected, however what I don't like about this solution is temporary type conversion to `unknown` i.e.:

```
const myRepositoryMock = <Repository><unknown>{/* ... */}
```

I use it for readability. Basically `Repository` has lots of methods from which just one is relevant to this particular test and I do not want to have them all explicitly listed in my mock.

Do you know if/how can I get rid of `<unknown>` type conversion w/o having to add all methods specified in `Repository` type to `myRepositoryMock`?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like an answer is:

```
const myRepositoryMock : Pick<Repository, "repositoryMethod"> = {/* ... */}
```

lmk if you come upon a better one.